# Find and append a block of text with another

Tags: bash, sed

I want to find a block of text and then append it with another block of text with sed.I couldn't find the right sed command because of the nature of the text involve.

Say i have a file that contain this text

```
[...]
    zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
    };
[...]
```

I want to append the following text to the same file after the text above has been found

```
zone    "$variable" {
    type master;
    file "$variable.fwd";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

Notice the special characters such as dot , " " , { } anad the presence of variables.The presense of such character make it a pain for me 
Can anybody show me how to achieve this with the use of heredoc 
Regards

Comment: What do you mean by `following text to the site`?

Comment: check my edit.The [..] indicate that the file contains other data as well

Answer (score 1):

A heredoc won't help a lot here.

```
sed -ni '1h;1!H;${g;s/    zone "." IN {\
        type hint;\
        file "named.ca";\
    };\
/&zone    "$variable" {\
    type master;\
    file "$variable.fwd";\
    allow-update { none; };\
};\
/;p}' file
```

For explanation see [Multi-line sed search and replace](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/27/20-Multi-line-sed-search-and-replace/).